# RecyclerView and background requests with large collection of items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a *RecyclerView* with a large collection bound to it, say 500+ items.   When `onBindViewHolder` is called I make a async HTTP request to load some data.

But when I scroll really fast down the list, how do i cancel the requests for all items that are no longer in view?  I am seeing 100's of requests start in the background because of how RecyclerView loads, i think onBindViewHolder is called for every item i scroll past?

I was thinking to kick off a request in `onBindViewHolder` that waits 500ms and if the item bound to it is still in view / still the same then starts the async request.  Would this work?  If so then how do i check if the item is in view still from within the Adapter ?

What's the correct way to solve this problem?

Comment: You can use a endless scroll design. For example, you first load 50 items. If the user reaches the bottom, then load 50 more. I have some weird errors when using `RecyclerView` with asynchronous call. So, I don't recommend doing it.

Answer (score 7):

You can make a `OnScrollListener` for `RecyclerView`:

```
 public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE){
        int firstVisibleItem = view.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        int lastVisiblePosition = view.getLastVisiblePosition();

        //call request from firstVisibleItem to lastVisiblePosition 

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. From this method am I updating the collection bound to my RecyclerView Adaptor directly or do I get access to the ViewHolder and update those?

Comment: Here you can call a function in adapter to load data (pass position of view). You can write any thing in the function, access viewholder or not.

Comment: I got this to work for updating the Adapter, but i don't think its efficient.  I don't want to load all data for all items in my adapter, I'd rather just update the individual view holder objects.  What's a clean way to access View holders from here?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `setTag()` in `View` to save the connection reference, like this

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection;
    if (holder.itemView.getTag() != null) {
        httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)holder.itemView.getTag();
        //close the connection
        httpURLConnection.disconnect();
    }
    // create your connection
    httpURLConnection = new HttpURLConnection();
    holder.itemView.setTag(httpURLConnection);
}
```